# Xcode Return key places cursor in middle of line

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts, carriage-return

In Xcode 3.2.5 I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to center the content (just testing out some shortcuts) and now whenever I hit <kbd>Return</kbd>, the cursor starts in the centre of the next line, instead of at the beginning. (Almost like an invisible tab stop in Pages)

How do I get my normal <kbd>Return</kbd> functionality back?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and was able to fix it like this:
Xcode>Preferences>Indentation>Syntax-aware-indenting>automatically indented characters: UNCHECK RETURN box.
Apply
This worked for me, otherwise it would always position cursor in the middle of the new line.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I forgot to close a parentheses.